# Re-sampling inquiry

Tags: python, scikit-learn, resampling

I have a bit of confusion here using sklearn.utils resample.

Using an imbalanced dataset, I am trying to randomly down-sample the majority class. Everything works smoothly but when I just realized that the performance of my model with (replace= True) does significantly improve.

What is the reason behind this increased performance here? Are samples replaced with copied samples? Is there any overfitting here?

I am somehow new to this and so, therefore, would really appreciate any clarifications here.

This is the part of the code that does the whole significant changes.

```py
from sklearn.utils import resample

Negative = sms[sms.Label == 'Neg']
Positive = sms[sms.Label == 'Pos']


# Upsample minority class
df_Negative_res = resample(Negative , replace=True,  # sample with replacement
                        n_samples=243 ,  # to match majority class
                        random_state=seed )  # reproducible results

df_Positive_res = resample(Positive , replace=True,  # sample with replacement
                        n_samples=243 ,  # to match majority class
                        random_state=seed)  # reproducible results

# Combine majority class with upsampled minority class
sms = pd.concat([df_Negative_res, df_Positive_res])

print(sms)
```

Comment: How does your model perform on the test data?

Comment: I am using cross-validation actually, with 5 CV.

Answer (score 1):

By doing over/undersampling you actually change the distribution of your imbalanced dataset and try to boost the performance of your model. So, it can be  actually considered as a boosting approach. There is already a discussion about resampling with replacement, so I would advice you to take a look at it:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171440/bootstrap-methodology-why-resample-with-replacement-instead-of-random-subsamp
In order to find out whether your model is overfitting, you need a large test-set (without any oversampling or so) and this test set has to be different from your train set. If your model performs good, the chances that it is overfitting are lower. But still, when doing over/undersampling you influence the bias of your data. 
So, the key is to find out if your model can generalize well on unseen samples. On the training set it should perform really good (in the general case).
There is also something very important you have to consider when doing cross validation - do you apply the sampling inside each fold or on the whole dataset? Here is a discussion on that topic https://www.researchgate.net/post/should_oversampling_be_done_before_or_within_cross-validation 
I hope my answer is helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful reply t_e_o. I am actually doing the resampling before the CV, so for the whole datasets. It may lead to overoptimism indeed. I will address that.

Comment: I hope I could give you two ups t_e_o

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, I would advise using pipeline and re-sampling from imbalanced-learn: https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/under-sampling/plot_comparison_under_sampling.html#prototype-selection-under-sampling-by-selecting-existing-samples

It will ease the evaluation by sampling the training dataset and not the testing dataset.